# How can we change the background color of a tr using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with class name `.myTab`,

```
<table class="table table-bordered myTabl">
    <tr style="background:#ff0">
       <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#f00">
       <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#ff0">
       <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#f00">
       <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now i want to check if there is any row having

```
background:#f00;
```

```
if ($(".myTabl table tr").css("background-color") == "f00"){
  $(".myTabl table tr").css({"background-color":"ff0"});
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: background and background-color are two different properties, which means you are checking for a CSS attribute thats not there.

Comment: Can't you use classes instead of inline styles?

Comment: @Arjan what do you suggest instead of my code?

Comment: @mus classes are not recommended due to some other means

Comment: `.myTabl table tr` doesn’t select anything with the HTML you have shown, you don’t have a table _inside_ of `.myTabl`. And in addition to what @Arjan said, you don’t necessarily get color values returned back by the browser in the same format you set them.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of going through all the rows within your table and checking if the color is yellow (`#ff0`) you can instead select all the yellow rows by using this as the selector:

```
$('.table tr[style*="background:#ff0;"]')
```

And then change the matched elements' background colors to red (`#f00`):

```
.css({"background-color": "#f00"});
```

See working example below:

```js
$('.table tr[style*="background:#ff0;"], .table tr[style*="background:#ffff00;"]').css({
  "background-color": "#f00"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered myTabl">
  <tr style="background:#ff0;">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#f00;">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#ff0;">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#f00;">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#ffff00;">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#ff00ff;">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This work only if style contain one property `background`

Comment: What happens if I have `background-color: #ff00ff`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan isn't `#ff00ff` magenta? If you want it to work with `#ffff00` you could expand the selector `$('.table tr[style*="background:#ff0"], .table tr[style*="background:#ffff00"]` to work with

Comment: Yep, but my point is that your `[style*="background:#ff0"]` selector will match that colour and any which begins with `#ff0`

Comment: Ah, I see now. I suppose if `;` were used in the style attribute this could be avoided

Answer (score 1):

Loop through rows and in function get `style` attribute of `tr` and using regex find hex value of `background` and check it.

```js
$(".myTabl tr").each(function(){
  var match = $(this).attr("style").match(/background\s*:\s*#(\w+)/);
  if (match != null && match[1] == "f00")
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered myTabl">
  <tr style="background:#ff0">
     <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#f00; font-size:12px">
     <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#ff0">
     <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="font-size:12px; background   :   #f00">
     <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer is working too, but the first one is i think very suitable for my problem

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues with your logic here. Firstly you need to loop through all the `tr` elements and work on them individually. You also need to fix your selector as `.myTabl` *is* the `table`, so the additional `table` selector is incorrect.

Then if you check the output from `css('background-color')` you'll see it's in `rgb()` format, not hex, or a plain colour name. As such you need to test for that in your `if` condition. Try this:

```js
$(".myTabl tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css('background-color').toLowerCase() === "rgb(255, 255, 0)") {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#f00");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered myTabl">
  <tr style="background:#ff0">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#f00">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#ff0">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#f00">
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That being said, it would be much simpler if you just used classes to set the colours.